# Custom Django SlugField Validation Breaks URL Matching

Tags: django, validation, django-urls, slug

I wrote a custom field validator for slugs in my URLs (accepting periods in slugs for one model, `SLUG_REGEX = '[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$'`):

```
def validate_my_slug(value):

    my_slug_re = re.compile(settings.SLUG_REGEX)

    if not my_slug_re.match(value):
        raise ValidationError(
            _('Slugs must consist of letters, numbers, '
              'underscores, hyphens, or periods.'),
            params={'value': value},
        )
```

The field in `models.py`:

```
slug = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True, 
                        validators=[validate_my_slug])
```

This works when saving models in Django admin. But then in my URLConf, this no longer works (it did work before changing the slug validation):

```
path('product-release/<slug:slug>', ProductReleaseDetail.as_view(), 
     name='product-detail')
```

1. I found a solution using `re_path`, but I'm not sure it's the right/best way to do it:

   ```
    re_path('product-release/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)$', 
            ProductReleaseDetail.as_view(), 
            name='product-release-detail')
   ```
2. Now this no longer works (comes before the `re_path` pattern above in `urls.py`):

   ```
    path('product-releases', ProductReleaseList.as_view(), 
         name='product-release-list')
   ```

Everything works except those matches to product release list. When I changed the slug validator, the URL `http://localhost:8080/product-releases` stopped working, with the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /product-releases
Reverse for 'product-release-detail' with no arguments not found.
1 pattern(s) tried: ['product-release/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$)']
```

But this seems wrong since I'm not even trying to reach `product-release-detail`; I'm trying to reach `product-release-list`. I must be missing something simple here, but now my vision is clouded.

**`views.py`**

```
. . .

class ProductReleaseList(ListView):
    model = ProductRelease


class ProductReleaseDetail(DetailView):
    model = ProductRelease

. . .
```

**`urlpatterns`**

```
. . .

# Product Releases
path('product-releases', ProductReleaseList.as_view(), name='product-release-list'),
re_path('product-release/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$)', ProductReleaseDetail.as_view(), name='product-release-detail'),
# Release Notes
path('release-notes', ReleaseNoteList.as_view(), name='release-note-list'),
re_path('release-note/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$)', ReleaseNoteDetail.as_view(), name='release-note-detail'),

. . .
```

**`productrelease_list.html`**

```
. . .

<h4><a href="{% url 'product-release-detail' %}">{{ p }}</a></h4>

. . .
```

Comment: 1) looks good, but 2) makes no sense. Please post the urlpatterns in full by copying. You likely forgot a comma or bracket somewhere.

Comment: OK, but no warnings or errors in IDE, plus the rest of the site and code works. I'll an update shortly.

Comment: Now it makes sense. The url matches correctly for the list view, but in the template you're using {% url %} and that now fails.

Comment: I've updated the question with some more detail. I'm still unsure why `product-releases` isn't getting matched or, rather, why the slug regex is being used here. It's just a regular generic view to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you're using something akin to:

```html
{% url "product-release-detail" varname %}
```

This variable however can apparently be empty (or is even always empty due to a spelling mistake). With `/<slug:slug>` this goes through (which I don't agree with btw, but that's besides the point). With your more restrictive and better `re_path`, this now generates an error (correctly), because `/product-release/` is not a valid url: a slug should at least have one character.

So the root cause is ether, that the variable is incorrectly named or that you have products without slugs (which you shouldn't have).

#### Address comments

1. Commenting out in templates is done with `{# #}`. Make sure you didn't use `<!-- -->`, because that still executes the code.
2. As it stands `{% url "product-release-detail" %}` is invalid: it requires an argument, namely a slug. If you want to link to the list view, use `{% url "product-release-list" %}` as that can be called without argument.
3. I don't know what {{ p }} is, but I'm assuming the product object. In that case, you should use `{%url "product-release-detail" p.name_of_slug_field %}`.

Comment: My apologies. I'm working on some code that I wasn't comfortable sharing, so I attempted to cut away the unneeded bits to make it cleaner for this question. I think I actually clouded the question instead... You are right, but I've already tested this (eg, commented out `{% url product-release-detail %}` in my template. If you wouldn't mind, can you take a look at my edits? I've made it clearer (I hope). And I ensured that all product releases and all release notes have slugs in the DB.

Comment: Thank you! That's working as expected. A fundamental part of using the `url` template tag completely escaped me. I was so mired in the other details (like the fact the "list" wasn't showing up). You even mentioned it needed an argument in your first response and I ignored it. Apologies... Thanks again, you've been most helpful.